# Ruby (1.8.1) -- ERRNO::EEXIST File exists

Tags: ruby, file

So I am working with Ruby, and...
I have an error `ERRNO::EEXIST, Script 'text' line 2 ... File exists`
The error occurs if a directory it created (defined in EGGPATH) already exists, which should work in itself because of `unless File.exist?(EGGPATH)`
While what I'm trying to do is:

```
def cyhm   #file text
  Dir.mkdir(EGGPATH) unless File.exist?(EGGPATH)
  File.open(EGGPATH + "/CAN YOU HEAR ME.txt", "w+") do |f|
    f.write("text")
  end
end
def cyhm_pt2
  Dir.mkdir(EGGPATH) unless File.exist?(EGGPATH)
  if File.exists?(EGGPATH + "/CAN YOU HEAR ME.txt") == false
    cyhm
  end
  File.open(EGGPATH + "/CAN YOU HEAR ME.txt", "a+") do |f|
    f.write("text2")
  end
end
```

While EGGPATH is defined here, in the other file:

```
TXTLIST = ["Ą", "ą", "Ć", "ć", "Ę", "ę", "Ł", "ł", "Ń", "ń", "Ó", "ó", "Ś", 
"ś", "Ź", "ź", "Ż", "ż"] #file randomtxt
EGGPAT = TXTLIST[rand(TXTLIST.size)] + TXTLIST[rand(TXTLIST.size)] + 
TXTLIST[rand(TXTLIST.size)] + TXTLIST[rand(TXTLIST.size)] + 
TXTLIST[rand(TXTLIST.size)] + TXTLIST[rand(TXTLIST.size)] + 
TXTLIST[rand(TXTLIST.size)] + TXTLIST[rand(TXTLIST.size)] + 
TXTLIST[rand(TXTLIST.size)] + TXTLIST[rand(TXTLIST.size)] + 
TXTLIST[rand(TXTLIST.size)]
if File.exists?(SAVEPATH + "\\MODAR\\eseggdir.es") == false
  File.open(SAVEPATH + "\\MODAR\\eseggdir.es", "w+") do |f|
    f.write(EGGPAT)
  end
end
EGGPATH = File.read(SAVEPATH + "\\MODAR\\eseggdir.es")
```

Also, don't tell me to switch to a newer version of Ruby, cause I'm working with RPGXP, and I don't want to change it anytime soon...

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: ....................yea. Actually, how to solve the problem if it wasn't obvious.

Comment: Can you please explain the problem and your question in clear, unambiguous language? [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may help you with formulating your question. You should also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Akino "the problem" _isn't_ obvious. You're describing a behaviour that arises predictably from writing this code.

Comment: The question is poorly worded. Also, running this (with a slight modification so the paths from the first file are shared to the second), everything works as expected so it's not clear what you're asking. If I had to take a shot in the dark I'd go with "path issue" due to how you're escaping paths with `\\`. You might try using join for path concatenation https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/File.html#method-c-join

Comment: @JayDorsey It didn't work, uh, the problem is most likely related to "unless File.exist?(EGGPATH)", since the script is behaving like that line wouldn't even exist, it's trying to create the same directory twice, which of course results in this error.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it like that in the first place, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out that Ruby cannot stand checking the file names that have characters other than English alphabet in them. Shame. So that's the solution, I'll have to recreate the TXTLIST array to:
`TXTLIST = ["A", "b", "C", "D", "e", "F", "g", "H", "i", "J", "k", "L", "m", "N", "o", "P", "r", "S", "t", "U", "w", "y", "X", "z", "Q", "v", "a", "B", "c", "d", "E", "f", "G", "h", "I", "j" "K", "l", "M", "n", "O", "p", "R", "r", "S", "t", "U", "w", "Y", "x", "Z", "q", "V"]` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because the directory `MODAR` doesn't exist on your system. Something like below should fix it:

```
modar_path = File.join(SAVEPATH, 'MODAR')

unless Dir.exists?(modar_path)
  Dir.mkdir(modar_path)
end
```

There's another command that might work:

```
require 'fileutils'
# replace modar_path with the path you choose, or set it as I did above
FileUtils.mkdir_p(modar_path)
```